# Error in the Bounty FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, terminology

In the [bounty FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) it says

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least ***2 upvotes*** will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

It should be `a scoring vote of 2 or greater`, (or whatever terminology is used). When I say that it should be a scoring vote of 2 or greater I mean that that's how the system actually works and therefore the FAQ needs to be fixed.

Comment: Is there a standard SE term for the vote sum?

Comment: @zyx I suspect it's just "score". E.g. the badge descriptions use this.

Comment: @zyx - Yes - "score == upvotes - downvotes".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updated to state:

```
with a minimum score of 2
```

Instead of:

```
with at least 2 upvotes
```

Comment: Thank you.${{}}$